# How can I show an apostrophe in the placeholder text on a rails form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I want have my form have a placeholder like

> Please enter the store's address

How can I edit the form below to get the apostrophe to work?

```
<%= text_area_tag 'store', '', class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Please enter the store's address' %>
```

Comment: placeholder: 'Please enter the store\'s address'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape apostrophe with backslash:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'store', '', class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Please enter the store\'s address' %>
```

or use string literal with quotation marks:

```
<%= text_area_tag 'store', '', class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Please enter the store's address" %>
```